# Sumset of $k$-smooth numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Take the set $T(k,n)=M_1(k,n)$ of all $k$ smooth numbers less than $n$.

1. What is the cardinality of $$\{1,\dots,n\}\cap M_2(k,n)$$ where every integer in $M_2(k,n)$ is the sum of two integers in $M_1(k,n)$?
2. Instead of $M_2(k,n)$ how would the behavior be for $M_i(k,n)$ where every integer is sum of $i$ integers in $T(k,n)$?

Comment: It is essentially like $((\log n)^k)^i)$, as smooth numbers tend to thin out when n is like exp(k).  Gerhard "Log Smooth Is Really Smooth" Paseman, 2020.05.06.

Comment: Is there any dependence of k on n?

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I think that's an upper bound?

Comment: You could take a look at the Croot's paper ''On a combinatorial method for counting smooth numbers in sets of integers'', Journal of Number Theory 126 (2007) 237–253. In particular, Theorems 3 and 4 there could be useful to your situation.